# what does strlen do if it encounter a space in between char array?

Tags: c++, strlen

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char b[] = {'a','b',' ','c'};
    cout << sizeof(b) << endl;
    cout << strlen(b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why the above output is 4,6 isnt that 4,4 is the correct answer?

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of your code is undefined: `strlen` requires that `b` **must** contain a `NUL` character within the bounds of the array.

(Note that `' '` is a space, **not** `NUL`. A space is processed no differently by `strlen` to any other non-`NUL` character.)

If you had written

```
char b[5]={'a','b',' ','c'};
```

then C++ would have set the final element of `b` to 0 (i.e. `NUL`) for you.

Comment: Alternatively (for not having to specify array size): `char b[] = { 'a', 'b', ' ', 'c', 0 };`

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits *undefined behavior*:

The behavior of `strlen` is not defined if the argument passed to it is not `NUL`-terminated.

You seem to confuse the NUL character with the space character.

Comment: `hex 20` - Unfounded assumption if one is to be a pedant

Comment: Feel free to take my wording which I prefer: the argument doesn't need to be NUL-terminated, it just needs to have NUl somewhere in it,

Comment: @StoryTeller: Pedantic? You'll have the mainframe dudes after you.

Comment: hex 20 in ascii/utf-8 (and a bunch other) indeed. Will edit.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I'm trying to save Nax here from their wrath :)

Comment: @Nax: Note that ASCII is *very, very* different from UTF-8.

Comment: And ASCII is also a *possible* character set. Not *the* character set. No matter how common it is.

Comment: @StoryTeller: My father has already left his house, and has just dumped the clutch in his 911 at 6000 revs. He's off somewhere in a hurry. Nax, run for the hills.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Indeed, but the difference is not relevant for the 128 first characters of both charsets.

Comment: @Nax - It's perfectly valid for a C implementation to use something like [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (what Bathsheba was alluding to). I suggest you remove the hex mention, it really is detracting from your answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I know that, I was responding to their comment about the difference between ASCII and UTF-8. The hex mention was supposed to help OP figure out that the space and NUL characters have different values, but it's making us dive into the topic of character sets, which was not OP's question. I will remove it.

Comment: Stand down please daddy.

Answer (score 1):

> what does strlen do if it enounter a space in between char array?

While all the other answers (according to your code sample, legitimately!!!) hint to the undefined behaviour due to the missing null character within your array, I'll be answering your original question:

Nothing special, it will count the space just as any other character (especially, it *won't* stop processing the string as you seem to have assumed)...

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` traverses the array **until** it encounters a `NULL` character. Your array does not contain `NULL` characters (ASCII 0) but it contains a space (ASCII 32).

So `strlen` continues **past** your array. It happens to exist a `NULL` character at position 6 (two characters after the end of the array in memory), so string length is 6. Subsequent executions of this function could return different values, as memory content outside the array is undefined. It may also crash.

Comment: why it happens to exist that null character ,two characters after end of array

Comment: @T.g Just by accident. Your array occupies a bunch of bytes in memory. As on the stack, it is quite likely that there are some other (uninitialised!!!) bytes accessible (again: pure accident! - you could have quite well run into an access violation instead), and one of these bytes (the 6th one) "happened" to contain a null value, but it could have contained any other value as well...

Comment: @T.g data after the array is unitialized (read: random)